# A SparkSession already exists when building on Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-devops

I am trying to initialize a SparkSession on Azure VM when building our pipeline. The code is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
jars_to_load = ['jarfile1.jar', 'jarfile2.jar']
builder = (
    SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('MySparkSession')
    .config("spark.jars", ",".join(jars_to_load))
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "unique-value")
    .master("local[*]")
)
spark = builder.getOrCreate()
print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll())
```

I am printing all the attributes of the spark context so that I can see that the session gets built properly. Specifically, I am interested to see if the JAR files are set. What I see is that when I am running locally, everything is good. If I print out `spark.sparkContext.appName` I can see that it has value `MySparkSession` and same goes for the other config settings. However, when it is running on Azure's Linux VM, I get a warning
`WARN SparkSession: Using an existing Spark session; only runtime SQL configurations will take effect.`
indicating that there is some global/local session in place. Setting `appName` should replace the existing session but it does not. Hence, if I print out `spark.sparkContext.appName` during the pipeline run it outputs LocalApp and all the attributes set as config in the builder, e.g., `spark.jars` are empty `None`. It seems that I cannot replace the existing `SparkSession`. What I have also tried is setting the spark configurations after the `getOrCreate` method, e.g., `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate` and then `spark.set.conf` however this errors with

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException:  Cannot modify the value of a Spark config: spark.jars. See also 'https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#ddl-statements'`

Note that it is not possible to load from Maven directly firstly because of the firewall, and secondly because even if it's not the JAR files, other config settings do not get configured properly, like, `sql.extensions`. I also checked the environment setup steps to make sure that some spark session does not get created in console during the VM initialization, but I cannot seem to find anything.

Anyone has had a similar problem? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The warning indicates the sparksession already exists, please try to stop SparkSession before `builder.getOrCreate()` to create the new SparkSession.

As per the [doc](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/sparksession-explained-with-examples/):

[image]

Comment: I will try this as soon as possible; thanks. My question is primarily: why does it already exist?

Comment: Before your pipeline, try to call `spark.sparkContext.isActive` on local machine, this returns true if it is active otherwise false. Also check if you are running the devops agent with same user, you can add  whoami in deovps bash task to check the user name.

Comment: Can you be more precise by 'try to call `spark.sparkContext.isActive` on local machine'; my understanding is that the local machine is installed (Linux VM) during the pipeline run, so I am unsure what you mean by 'before the pipeline'. Can you also explain why would the user make any difference? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Are you using self-hosted agent or Microsoft-Hosted agent? If you are using self-hosted one, you can check the value `spark.sparkContext.isActive` before you run the pipeline. If it's Microsoft-Hosted one, please double check the script. But no matter which agent you are using, try to stop the session ahead for a check.

Comment: I did stop the session. I did sort of a hacky way where I do `spark = builder.getOrCreate()` then I stop it `spark.stop()` and then I build it again `spark = builder.getOrCreate()`. It ain't pretty but it's working. It would be good to know why does another session exist before I run the builder but alright.

Comment: Glad to know it works. Regarding why another session exists before the builder, `builder.getOrCreate()` method will check if there's existing session firstly, from current code, it's hard to say the cause, but it's recommended to call `spark.stop()` to stop the session after finishing the Spark job, in this scenario, check if the session still exists before getorCreate() method in `new` build.